# Stackoverflow keep asking me for reCaptcha

Tags: bug, mobile-web

On my mobile phone everytime I ask or answer a question it asks me to fill in a reCaptcha. How can I prevent this. I am using Opera Mini 10 on a Nokia C6.

Comment: Stay in one place so you keep the same IP address. Mobile phones are assigned new IP addresses as they move from cell tower to cell tower, and that triggers reCaptcha checks. Opera Mini also uses proxy servers that 'compress' the page, and those servers will use different IP addresses as well.

Comment: That could have something to do with Opera Mini using a render farm and a proxy to server you the pages.

Comment: @Stijn: good point.

Comment: @MartjinPieters OK

Comment: Note that Opera Mini is [officially **not** supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)